# Installation of certificate in iOS simulator failed

Tags: ios, certificate, ios-simulator, provisioning-profile

I have a CA certificate (signed by my own) and want it installed in simulators. I dragged it into the window of simulator and it asked me to install. Surely it was marked as a red "unverified" but I kept installing it. After all, when I clicked DONE, it dispeared! In the "Profile": No profiles are currently installed.

I tried the same thing again. This time it was marked as a green "verified". But when I clicked INSTALL, I got a warning: the uuid for the profile is not unique. And then it failed.

I also tried to reboot this simulator but seemed no help. I reset the content of this simulator and redid the same thing, but nothing changed. Could anyone help me and make it installed? Thanks a lot.

PS: The CA certificate was created by myself with [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggeyj/index.html) and nothing went wrong during the creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profile Management is not supported in the iOS Simulator.